# How to split Japanese Date which include month and year into or Date format

Tags: date, kotlin, simpledateformat

I want to split Japanese date which  is in format "2020年7月" into separate array so that can get the year and month from that.

I tried SimpleDateFormatter to format Japanese date with and have the year and date separated with "/"but the output is wrong:

Tried this code:

```
   val inputFormat = SimpleDateFormat("YYYY年M月")
   val date = inputFormat.parse("2020年7月")
   val outputText = SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM").format(date)
```

input :2020年7月
output:2020/12

Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Is the output example the expected / desired one or the actual wrong one?

Comment: use lowercase `y` for year

Comment: or use `u` for a year

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `YearMonth` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `java.time` for this because the datetime classes from `java.util` are outdated (but still not deprecated).

The following example shows a way using a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` for parsing a `String` formatted according to a certain pattern and a `java.time.YearMonth`, a class obviously designed for the purpose of creating a month in a year without respect to a day of month:

```kotlin
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

fun main() {
    val jpYearMonth = "2020年7月"
    val japaneseDtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu年M月")
    val yearMonth = YearMonth.parse(jpYearMonth, japaneseDtf)
    println(yearMonth.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM")))
}
```

In order to achieve your desired output this code has to use a different `DateTimeFormatter` defining the output pattern because the default pattern (internal use when you just `println(yearMonth)`) would be hyphon-separated (`2020-07`):

```
2020/07
```

Comment: @OleV.V. Right, I just wanted to try this myself (never did before) and then I shared the result without checking for duplicates. My fault...

Comment: @OleV.V. That's the *era* I'm currently in... I will try to remind myself about the check for duplicates. The `YearMonth` is even cooler, anyway.

Comment: @OleV.V. I just found some time to follow your advice. Unfortunately, the output by using a `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu/MM")` doesn't look like a japanese era ;-) . I'm interested in possibilities of creating a `JapaneseDate` or `JapaneseEra`, but I doubt finding time for it today.

Comment: @OleV.V. Maybe something to ask in a different question... Later on...